# Having trouble with setup of Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm quite new to Java and Eclipse. I'm attempting to build a simple program to read information from excel documents using Apache POI.

I've created a project, an ExcelReadWrite class, and imported what I thought were the correct modules. As you can see from the code all I am currently trying to do get the last row num to verify the program is working.

The two errors I'm getting are:
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**
The image below shows the 4 modules I added as well as the errors at the bottom

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ExcelReadWrite {

    private static Workbook wb;
    private static Sheet sh;
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    private static FileOutputStream fos;
    private static Row row;
    private static Cell cell;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fis = new FileInputStream("./testdata.xlsx");
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int numOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(numOfRows);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please visit this blog http://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following dependencies to make it work:

- [commons-codec-1.11.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11)
- [commons-collections4-4.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.2)
- [commons-math3-3.6.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1)
- [commons-compress-1.18.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18)
- [curvesapi-1.05.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.virtuald/curvesapi/1.05)

Comment: Add the dependencies and the program is working. Thank you Victor.